# Spring PDF generation + i18n

Tags: java, spring, itext

I have a spring application that overloads an AbstractView in order to generate a PDF file. That file should be internationalized too, so I am adding appropriate strings from resources. There are a lot of code in such implementation.
So mabe there is another way to implement it? I know that Flying Saucer can do that conversion but does it provide an i18n?
Ideally I want some template engine with i18n support and PDF generation tools.
Does anybody familiar with such engine?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps IText or JasperReports is what you need.

Comment: I am using iText already. And doesjasperReports support i18n?

Answer (score 0):

It's not trivial, since for unicode characters to be presented in PDF, they must either come from one of provided fonts, or from embedded font. You must prepare yourself the set of fonts, that will support all languages that may be used.

Comment: This behaviour is caused by PDF specification itself.